# Matrix Cross Product

Tags: matrix, evaluation

This is a simple question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Let's just say, for the sake of simplicity, that I wanted to find the cross product of the follow matrices:

```
m1={{1,2},{3,4};
m2={{5},{6}};
```

Using the command "Cross" gives an error that these are unequal length and therefore cannot be combined. I know these two can be combined (because I can do it by hand in this simple case: $1\times 5 + 2\times 6$ and $3\times 5 + 4\times 6$). But I want to be able to have the process down for more complicated expressions. I could create a Module that would do all of that work for me, but shouldn't there just be a command for the cross product of matrices?

I feel like I'm missing something, but I can't find what I need... Shouldn't

```
m1 x m2
```

just work? What's going wrong?

EDIT:
Apparently, the dot product in mathematica (in terms of matrices) is what does this thing. Issued solved.

Comment: What do you mean by "the cross product of matrices"? The cross product is only defined for three- and seven-dimensional vectors, is it not? If you just mean the *product* of the matrices—as it appears you do—what you want is just `m1.m2`.